# Problem with statically linking hunspell library in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, static-linking, hunspell

I can't statically link hunspell library to my C++ project in Visual Studio 2010.

I downloaded hunspell and went to `hunspell-1.3.1\src\win_api` folder. I opened libhunspell.vcproj file in visual studio 2010 and converted project. I built solution in `Realease` configuration and it generated "libhunspel.lib" file in `hunspell-1.3.1\src\win_api\Release\libhunspell` folder.

In my simple C++ console program that use hunpell:

- I added this folder with libhunspel.lib file in **Property Pages/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Library Directories**
- I added "hunspell-1.3.1\src\" folder to **Property Pages/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories**
- and "libhunspell.lib" to **Property Pages/Linker/Input/Additional Dependancies**.

But it still gives me unresolved external symbol error:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall Hunspell::spell(char const *,int *,char * *)" (__imp_?spell@Hunspell@@QAEHPBDPAHPAPAD@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hunspell_learning\hunspell_learning\main.obj  hunspell_learning
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Hunspell::Hunspell(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (__imp_??0Hunspell@@QAE@PBD00@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hunspell_learning\hunspell_learning\main.obj  hunspell_learning
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Hunspell::~Hunspell(void)" (__imp_??1Hunspell@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hunspell_learning\hunspell_learning\main.obj  hunspell_learning
Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hunspell_learning\Debug\hunspell_learning.exe 1   1   hunspell_learning
```

I don't have idea what can be wrong. I also tries with dynamic library. Built Hunspell solution in `Release_dll` configuration and just changed **Include Directories** in my app to `hunspell-1.3.1\src\win_api\Release_dll\libhunspell` and it compiles. I only need to copy libhunspell.dll where my executable program is so dll will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put "#define HUNSPELL_STATIC"  somewhere in your stdafx.h.