# Simple C++ Console app using Hunspell

Tags: c++, hunspell

I've searched and found a bunch of articles on using Hunspell, but so far none of them have really helped me.  [C++ - Using HunSpell 1.3.2 with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703520/c-using-hunspell-1-3-2-with-visual-studio-2010)  seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do, but after following along with the question, answer, and linked material, I'm still having problems.

Basically, I'm pretty new to C++ and am trying to learn how to incorporate Hunspell into an application I'm working on.  Since this is new to me, I'm trying to start by creating a simple console app, and then going from there.

Here's what I have so far (again, I've followed all the steps outlined in the linked question)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <hunspelldll.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Hunspell *spellObj = (Hunspell *)hunspell_initialize("HunSpell-dic\\en_us.aff",
    "HunSpell-dic\\en_us.dic");

char str[60];
cin >> str;

int result = hunspell_spell(spellObj, str);

if (result==0)
    cout << "Spelling Error!";
else
    cout << "Correct Spelling!";

hunspell_uninitialize(spellObj);
return 0;
}
```

I've added the paths to my configuration properties, and to the Linker, but when I build, I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__hunspell_uninitialize referenced in function _wmain    C:\Users\owner\Documents\My Code Vault\Sandbox\2010Sandbox\Console_Spellcheck\Console_Spellcheck.obj    Console_Spellcheck
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__hunspell_spell referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\owner\Documents\My Code Vault\Sandbox\2010Sandbox\Console_Spellcheck\Console_Spellcheck.obj    Console_Spellcheck
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__hunspell_initialize referenced in function _wmain  C:\Users\owner\Documents\My Code Vault\Sandbox\2010Sandbox\Console_Spellcheck\Console_Spellcheck.obj    Console_Spellcheck
Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\owner\Documents\My Code Vault\Sandbox\2010Sandbox\Debug\Console_Spellcheck.exe Console_Spellcheck
```

I'm sure that it's just something simple I've missed being new to this, but I've been pulling my hair for a few hours on it with no luck so far.  Any suggestions would be met with unbridled gratitude :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to find the answer.  After reading: [Problem with statically linking hunspell library in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232409/problem-with-statically-linking-hunspell-library-in-visual-studio-2010?rq=1), I tried #define HUNPSPELL_STATIC in my stdafx.h file, and that resolved the error I was encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the .lib file as an additional linker input dependency

Comment: Tried that with same results.  I have to be doing something wrong here.  Even after building the project (before I got to the errors), It never generated a libhunspell.dll file.  I've poured over all the instructions I've found, but I think that I'm just so new at this I'm missing something that was left out as a "taken for granted" item.